# how to stretch image within points in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have an arrow image which I have to stretch within points in my touchable application. When user will click on first point and he will dragged his pointer to next point an arrow image will be show from first point to second point in any direction of screen. When he will move through the points image should become big ( like a big arrow).

I wrote some part of code but it is looking ok in horizontal direction. How will I show image in diagonal look. I am thinking I will have to rotate image for diagonal direction selection. But how will I know the exact angle of rotation? Here is my part of code.

```
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   CGPoint curentTouchPoint=[self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];


if(arrow.tag==200 && arrow!=nil) {
         [self removeChildByTag:200 cleanup:YES];
} 

CCLOG(@" cuurent touch point y=%f, prevvalue X=%f current X=%f",curentTouchPoint.y,prevValue.x,curentTouchPoint.x);

    arrow=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"arrow.png"];
    arrow.tag=200;
    arrow.scaleX=(curentTouchPoint.x-prevValue.x)/[arrow boundingBox].size.width;
    arrow.position=ccp(prevValue.x,prevValue.y);
    [self addChild:arrow];




}

   -(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(arrow!=nil) {
     [self removeChildByTag:200 cleanup:NO];
    arrow=nil;
    }

    CCLOG(@"Touch End");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the angle to rotate by calculating the slope and then converting it into degrees by multiplying with 180/PI.

So the slope of the line segment with points curentTouchPoint and prevValue is

m = (prevValue.y-curentTouchPoint.y)/(prevValue.x-curentTouchPoint.x)

The result m is in radians so inorder to convert it into radians multiply by 180/PI

m = (prevValue.y-curentTouchPoint.y)/(prevValue.x-curentTouchPoint.x)* 180/(22/7)

Also the rotation is done to the downside. and the angle m is the angle that the line makes with the x-axis so we have to multiply by -1;
So the final code becomes

```
arrow.rotation = -(prevValue.y-curentTouchPoint.y)/(prevValue.x-curentTouchPoint.x)* 180/(22/7);
```